# Short story about mining crew on planet expecting ship to return them to Earth and realizing it's not going to come

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

It's about a mining crew who have been  recruited with promises of being set up for life once they return from their time on the planet. They gradually realise they are not going to get home, the mining company does not want to spend the money on a rescue ship. I think they get a radio message left by the previous crew who are on a base on a different part of the planet and are now all dead.

Comment: Hi there! That's some useful info already but could you maybe take a look at [thse guidelines](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in?